# Select rows from my table where a character column matches a pattern

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, pattern-matching, regular-expression

I'm using Postgres 9.5. I have a `name` column of type "character varying".  I wonder how to select rows where the column begins with a number, followed by a space, followed by any other data.

So I would want rows where the column looks like:

```
12 DAVE
1 abcDEF
12345 LAST
```

But not when it looks like:

```
MYCOLUMN
1TEXT
=END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  name ~ '^\d+ .+';
```

The regular expression explained:

`^` .. start of string
`\d`  .. class shorthand for digits
`+` .. 1 or more of the preceding atom
 .. plain space
`.+` .. any character, again 1 or more of those

There are many different characters that look like a space. `' '` is just the plain space character. You might want to use the class shorthand `\s` instead to cover all of them.